# Signal error from portable class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah, base-class-library

I'm using a portable class library project that is performing some parsing. It's used from a aspnet mvc project. In some cases the parsing goes wrong and I need to eat the exception. However, I still want to log it using Elmah.
Since it's a portable class library project, I can't use Elmah.ErrorSignal.

```
public class ErrorHandledDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: I want to save ex here so I can retrieve it and log it to elmah in the upper layers when returning.
            return null; //Treat illegal dates like missing/empty nodes, ie a null value.
        }
    }
}
```

If it was a normal project (and I for some reason couldn't use Elmah.ErrorSignal) I'd use HttpContext and put the exceptions there.
How can I give the exception to the outer layer?

Comment: Why do you need to eat the exception?

Comment: Because the json can contain faulty dates and the parsing dies if one occurs. (They occur in irrelevant fields, but still kills the joy.)